# Read MathType object, convert MathType object to image

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, mathtype

I have a docx file that contains mathematical formulas created by mattype.
Is there a way to read its contents using java, poi?
Or convert all of those formulas created by mathtype to images?

*Example document below :*
[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533749/4326551

Comment: It would be helpful for helpers if you could providing a sample `*.docx` file having such `MathType` formulas in it for downloading somewhere. I believe the amount of possible helpers having knowledge about `apache poi` will be greater than the amount of possible helpers having knowledge about `apache poi` **and** having `MathType` installed. You don't think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathType equation in word is composed of wmf and ole bin. You can get the wmf and convert it to raster format, png\jpg , etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am involved in this project (XProc/XSLT/XML based):
http://transpect.github.io/modules-docx2tex.html

I am not sure if it is worth the setup time for a single conversion.
If you want to do it frequently, it absolutely is.

Once you have the tex, you can generate images from those sources.

If you really only want equations, then take a look at these single transpect modules:
mathtype2mml: https://github.com/transpect/mathtype-extension/
mml2tex: https://github.com/transpect/mml2tex